# Azure Data Flow: How to map csv to sql following table structure?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I have a raw csv in azure blob as follows:

[image: csv in blob]

I want to transform it as follows so that I can map it to the table:

[image: sql table structure]

If this is not possible in Azure data flow, then at least can we convert CSV to the expected SQL table format using excel functions?

Comment: hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score -1):

Based on my knowledge, there is no built-in feature to implement transpose.I suggest you using `azure function activity` before `data flow activity` to convert the data into the format as you want.

```
import csv
# import numpy as np

with open('D:/test1.csv', 'r') as csv_file:  # Opens the file in read mode
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    table = [row for row in csv_reader]
    header = table[0][0:2]+['Date','Value']
    dates = table[0][2:]
    newTable = [header]+[row[0:2]+[date, value] for row in table[1:] for date, value in zip(dates,row[2:])]
    print(newTable)
    # print(np.array(newTable))
```

Output as below:

[image]